# Using form_with with a self-referential resource in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, self-reference

I have a self-referential resource, `Node`, set up like this:

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'node_id', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'node_id'
end
```

It works fine on the console, but I want to be able to navigate to a node and create children nodes from there, and I'm having trouble doing so.

For example, if I open `/nodes/1`, there should be a form there, and every node I create from that form should automatically populate `node_id` with the current node's id, `1`.

How do I set up `form_with` and the `nodes_controller` so that it will allow me to achieve this?

The closest I got was by creating a special method (with the appropriate route):

```
def create_child
  @node = Node.new(node_params)
  @node.node_id = params[:id]

  if @node.save
    redirect_to node_path(params[:id])
  end
end

private
  def node_params
    params.require(:node).permit(:name)
  end
```

And then setting up the form like this:

```
<%= form_with url: "create_child" do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The request goes through, but then I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: node)
```

But as far as I can tell the `Node` object should have been created in the `create_child` method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've kind of solved it.

The form:

```
<%= form_with model: @node.children.build do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :node_id %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the controller:

```
def create
  @node = Node.new(node_params)

  if @node.save
    redirect_to @node.parent
  end
end
```

It's not perfect because it interferes with the displaying of the children nodes: if I put the form before the list of children, the list breaks. However, this is ok for my purposes, so I'll take it. Unless someone posts a better alternative I'll be accepting this as the answer.